# ruby error risen in ensure block hides error in main block

Tags: ruby, error-handling

I just realised that the following block of code will only raise '2', and hide raise '1'

```
2.3.8 :001 > begin
2.3.8 :002 >     raise '1'
2.3.8 :003?>   ensure
2.3.8 :004 >     raise '2'
2.3.8 :005?>   end
RuntimeError: 2
```

Is there a way to also have raise '1' to report?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Your code says "swallow error 1, and raise error 2 instead", so that's exactly what it does. Also, it's *weird* to `raise` inside an `ensure` block... The code is valid, I guess, but that's a bizarre logical flow.

Comment: Or to put this another way: If the above code did result in `RuntimeError: 1`, then wouldn't you be complaining "I said `ensure raise '2'`, so why isn't `2` being raised??"

Comment: To complement the other guys: no, you can't raise two errors at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

When your program is executed, it follows a path. When an exception is raised then your program is aborted and the exception bubbles back up.

By using `rescue` and/or `ensure` you are able to modify how exceptions are treated but there can always only be one exception that bubbles up.

But ruby is helpful in that it sets the `cause` when you `raise` an exception and a previous exception is present.

```rb
def raise_an_exception
  begin
    raise "cause"
  ensure
    raise "effect"
  end
end

begin
  raise_an_exception
rescue => e
  puts "'#{e.message}' was raised because '#{e.cause.message}'"
  # => 'effect' was raised because 'cause'
end
```

Is this what you are looking for?
Be aware that `cause` can also be `nil`!

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Exception.html#method-i-cause

Comment: "Be aware that cause can also be `nil`" well then we could go with `puts "'#{e.message}' was raised because '#{e.cause&.message}'"`

Answer (score 0):

You are telling ruby to always `raise '2'` by putting it in the `ensure` block - no matter what is done before hand (including the raising of errors). To have `raise '1'` report, you will need to remove the `ensure` block.